# variable not actualizing after ajax request

Tags: jquery, variables, validation

I have the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#btnRegister").click(function() {
        var errorVal=false;
        var numCorreo=0;
        var numAlias=0;

        $.ajax({
            url : "./php/auxChkUser.php",
            type : "POST",
            data : {alias : $("#txtRegisterAlias").val()},
            success: function(data){
                alert("usrdata: " + data);
                if(data>0) {
                    numAlias=data;
                    alert("<?=$lng->frmRegisterErrorUser; ?>");
                    errorVal=true;
                }
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                errorVal=true;
            } 
        });

        $.ajax({
            url : "./php/auxChkMail.php",
            type : "POST",
            data : {correo : $("#txtRegisterCorreo").val()},
            success: function(data){
                alert("maildata: " + data);
                if(data>0) {
                    numCorreo=data;
                    alert("<?=$lng->frmRegisterErrorCorreoExiste; ?>");
                    errorVal=true;
                }
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
                errorVal=true;
            } 
        });
        alert("numcorreo: " + numCorreo);
        alert("numalias: " + numAlias);
        alert(errorVal);
        if(!errorVal) $("#frmRegister").submit();
    });
});
```

This code makes this output:

```
maildata: 1
The mail already exists
usrdata: 1
The alias already exists
numcorreo: 0
numalias: 1
true
```

The problem is that the numCorreo variable is not being setted correctly. You would say that i have a boolean variable and that should be enought but i had this problem with the boolean variable before trying to get the number of maildata and usrdata. Any idea about whats happening here?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ajax requests are asynchronous. When you call: `alert("numcorreo: " + numCorreo);` The response from the server does not arrive yet and it displays the initialized value which is "0"

Comment: shit. I forgot to set it synchronous with "async: false,"...well...really thanx!